# Component tree not supported

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs2

How to solve the following errors in cli app?

backend.js:3638 App with id null not found

Is it bug in beta?

[image]

in console:

[image]

main.js (code)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
import DataTable from 'laravel-vue-datatable';
// import jQuery from 'jquery';
// window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';

import './assets/app.scss';
import './assets/styles/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/styles/custom.css';
import './assets/styles/themify-icons.css';
import './assets/styles/animate.css';
import './assets/styles/sublime.css';

// import './assets/styles/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

require('@/store/subscriber')

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://p3backend.test/api/'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(DataTable);
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));

store.dispatch('auth/attempt', localStorage.getItem('token')).then(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
})
```

Updated: I have 2 profiles in my chrome, on second profile vue-dev-tool is working fine :( tried to clean cache but still the same issue, the browser is up-to-date as `Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is in the Beta version of vue.js devtools!

try: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

**Steps:**

1. Uninstall/remove the current chrome extension.
2. Install the new version.
3. Happy using Vue.js devtools again :)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just removed the current extension and installed new one, problem fixed.